# What DB permissions are required for SQL Server Preview?

Tags: sql-server, deployment

In order to create the diff of possible schema changes, we would like to run sqlpackage.exe /Action=Script via an account with minimal permissions.  What permissions are required? The account we use to deploy is normally kept disabled as a control mechanism, and only enabled by particular gatekeepers. Having a second account get the script, and never having to disable that account, would save us time.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if the database already exists, the permissions required for a user to be used with sqlpackage script action are

```
db_ddladmin
```

and

```
VIEW DEFINITION
```

This is for SQL 2012; that we have used, not sure if it changes with further versions

Comment: db_ddladmin seems like what the OP is trying to avoid. That is, they're just trying to *read* the schema from the database in this phase of their deployment. I would try with just `view definition` first and see if that's sufficient.